# How do I get the count dark pixel of an image with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

How do I get the count of dark pixels of an image with numpy?

My picture is black and white so the dark pixel are black

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("myImage.PNG")
data = np.array(img)
```

Comment: how dark is a `dark pixel`?

Comment: my picture is black and white. so the dark pixel is black.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count number of white and black pixels in color picture in python? How to count total pixels using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803312/how-to-count-number-of-white-and-black-pixels-in-color-picture-in-python-how-to)

Answer (score 2):

If by dark pixel you mean the black color, then its value is 0. Numpy provides a function to count non-zero values in an array, `np.count_nonzero`, and to count zeroes you can do the following:

```
np.count_nonzero(data == 0)
```

You can set any other threshhold for the "darkness", e.g. `data <= 10`.

P.s. I am assuming that your image has only one channel (to make it sure, use `img = Image.open("myImage.PNG").convert('L')` to convert it to greyscale single channel image).

Comment: As an aside, grayscale .png files can have multiple channels (alpha / transparency). Depending on the format OP is dealing with, one may also need to select the appropriate channel.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, yes indeed. Thanks for pointing this out.